# 1.9 Related rewrite being ignored

Tags: magento-1.9, php, url-rewrite, class

I'm struggling with the following thing. Because I would like to write my own kind of filter for Related Products, I will have to rewrite the class "**Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Related**". While there has been proven the class I had to rewrite is being called, I cannot seem to edit anything inside the protected function "`_prepareData`". It isn't being called.

The situation currently: I have a class named "***My_Module_Block_Catalog_Product_List_Related***" which is extending the class *"**Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Related**"*. I have copied the protected function "`_prepareData()"` from the original class 
`(app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Related.php)`. But this function is not being called. If I test my class (if it is being called) by adding the following line of code:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->_prepareData();
}
```

and I add an echo to the protected function "`_prepareData()`" I can see my text is being echo'd correctly. However, the rest of the protected function "`_prepareData()`" is being ignored.
Also, if I remove the construct, the text will not be echo'd anymore.

I would like to show you my class and the original class.

**My class**

```
class My_Module_Block_Catalog_Product_List_Related extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Related {

    protected $_itemCollection;


    protected function _prepareData()
    {
        echo 'Test';
        $product = Mage::registry('product');
        /* @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */

        $this->_itemCollection = $product->getRelatedProductCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('required_options')
            ->setPositionOrder()
            ->addStoreFilter()
        ;


        if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_Checkout')) {
            Mage::getResourceSingleton('checkout/cart')->addExcludeProductFilter($this->_itemCollection,
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId()
            );
            $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($this->_itemCollection);
        }
//        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addSaleableFilterToCollection($this->_itemCollection);
        //Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($this->_itemCollection);
//NOTICE THE COMMENTED LINE ABOVE

        $this->_itemCollection->load();

        foreach ($this->_itemCollection as $product) {
            $product->setDoNotUseCategoryId(true);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**The class I am extending**

```
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Related extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Default MAP renderer type
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_mapRenderer = 'msrp_noform';

    protected $_itemCollection;

    protected function _prepareData()
    {
        $product = Mage::registry('product');
        /* @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */

        $this->_itemCollection = $product->getRelatedProductCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('required_options')
            ->setPositionOrder()
            ->addStoreFilter()
        ;

        if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_Checkout')) {
            Mage::getResourceSingleton('checkout/cart')->addExcludeProductFilter($this->_itemCollection,
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId()
            );
            $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($this->_itemCollection);
        }
//        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addSaleableFilterToCollection($this->_itemCollection);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($this->_itemCollection);

        $this->_itemCollection->load();

        foreach ($this->_itemCollection as $product) {
            $product->setDoNotUseCategoryId(true);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $this->_prepareData();
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }

    public function getItems()
    {
        return $this->_itemCollection;
    }

    /**
     * Get tags array for saving cache
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCacheTags()
    {
        return array_merge(parent::getCacheTags(), $this->getItemsTags($this->getItems()));
    }
}
```

I hope someone is able to help. Thanks!

**Edit:**
My config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Module>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </My_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>

        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_list_related>My_Module_Block_Catalog_Product_List_Related</product_list_related>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: show your module config.xml file? did you added rewrite code in that file ?

Comment: Yeah, it is. That's why _prepareData is being called in the constructor. 

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Module>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </My_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
       
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_list_related>My_Module_Block_Catalog_Product_List_Related</product_list_related>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>`

For a fixed identation, see my edited question. sorry, hah

Answer (score 1):

**In your module config.xml file, try to add below rewrite code in that file and check if that works**

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <module>
            <class>My_Module_Block</class>
        </module>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product_list_related>My_Module_Block_Catalog_Product_List_Related</product_list_related>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

Comment: I have modified my global element into your global element. Unfortunately it didn't change anything.